# Process foreign language in C++

Tags: c++

Hello I want to process Arabic language in my C++ code.

**My code**

```
int main() {
    wchar_t s[] = "ﺳﺄﻟﺘﻚِ ﺏﺎﻠﻠﻫ - ﻳﺎ ﻥﻭﺭ ﻊﻴﻨﻳ -\nﺏﺩﻮﻨﻳ ﻫﻞ ﻒﻳ ﺍﻟﺤﻴﺎﺓِ ﺣﻴﺎﺓ ؟\nﺖﻋﺎﻠ";
    for (auto ch : s) {
        cout << ch;
    }
}
```

I received an error

> error: int-array initialized from non-wide string

Also I tried **wstring**

```
int main() {
    wstring s = "ﺳﺄﻟﺘﻚِ ﺏﺎﻠﻠﻫ - ﻳﺎ ﻥﻭﺭ ﻊﻴﻨﻳ -\nﺏﺩﻮﻨﻳ ﻫﻞ ﻒﻳ ﺍﻟﺤﻴﺎﺓِ ﺣﻴﺎﺓ ؟\nﺖﻋﺎﻠ";
    for (wchar_t ch : s) {
        cout << ch;
    }
}
```

But received error

> conversion from ‘const char [148]’ to non-scalar type ‘std::__cxx11::wstring {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>}’ requested

Comment: just do  a prefix L" ... " for wide string

Comment: you might also want to use `std::wcout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```cpp
    wchar_t s[] =L"ﺳﺄﻟﺘﻚِ ﺏﺎﻠﻠﻫ - ﻳﺎ ﻥﻭﺭ ﻊﻴﻨﻳ -\nﺏﺩﻮﻨﻳ ﻫﻞ ﻒﻳ ﺍﻟﺤﻴﺎﺓِ ﺣﻴﺎﺓ ؟\nﺖﻋﺎﻠ";
```

The whole program is here :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    wchar_t s[] =L"ﺳﺄﻟﺘﻚِ ﺏﺎﻠﻠﻫ - ﻳﺎ ﻥﻭﺭ ﻊﻴﻨﻳ -\nﺏﺩﻮﻨﻳ ﻫﻞ ﻒﻳ ﺍﻟﺤﻴﺎﺓِ ﺣﻴﺎﺓ ؟\nﺖﻋﺎﻠ";
    for (auto ch : s) {
        std::cout << ch;
    }
}
```

The ouput of the execution is a list of `wchar_t`:

```sh
6520365156652476517665242161632651676516665248652486525932453265267651663265253652616519732652266526865256652673245106516765193652626525665267326525965246326523465267326516565247651886526865166651711616326518765268651666517132156710651746522765166652480
```

Answer (score 0):

Wide character literals and wide character string literals in C and C++ must be prefixed by L. For example: `L'A'`, `L"hello"`. Also, in this particular case, you likely will need to output into `std::wcout`.